# Image corrupted when trying to push from fabric.js to php

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a drawing app that I am building out using fabric.js and have a requirement to save the image server side. The code in place to do this is very simple, I have a form into which I push the canvas image using the following javascript:

```
jQuery(".send").click(function(){
canvas.deactivateAll();
if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
  alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
} else {
  var imageUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  //Lets update our form and post
  jQuery("#_image").val(imageUrl);
  jQuery("#_imageForm").submit();
}
```

});

On the server side the code is then looking for the posted b64 data and pushing it to a file:

```
    if (array_key_exists('_image', $_POST)) {
  $source = $_POST['_image'];   
  $urlUploadImages = "/images/";
  $nameImage = uniqid("image", true) . ".png";

  $saveFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $urlUploadImages . $nameImage;
  $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $source);
  $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
  file_put_contents($saveFile, base64_decode($image));
    }
```

This mostly works. The png is created and has content but it is truncated about 2/3 of the way down. The image created is 512px x 512px but the lower 1/3 is just transparent.

Looking at the raw encoded data, I can see that the length appear different and that there is also what appear to be some binary in the content. Is there anything else I should do to protect the content when submitting in this way?